# Repetitive code in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have been working on a small application in Meteor.  I have noticed a pattern of code that is starting to bug me.

```
Template.userForm.helpers({
    name: function(){
        user = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
        return user && user.profile.name;
    },

    _user_id: function(){
        user = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
        return user && user._id;
    },
    email: function(){
        user = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
        return user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address;
    },

});
```

The issue is seeing the `variable && variable.attribute` code repeated.  If I don't write the code that way I get errors about undefined variables.

Is there a better way to do this?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `return variable && variable.attribute` is equivalent to more elaborate

```
if(variable) return variable.attrubite;

return false;
```

This is necessary, because if `variable` was `null` - which happens all the time between page load and collection inflation - calling `variable.attribute` raises an exception: `null` does not have attributes.

So no, there's no escape from that check. You can choose another flavor if this one bothers you - personally, I'm leaving actual return for the last line and check correctness earlier:

```
if(! variable) return null;

return variable.attribute;
```

What can be avoided, is this line - which is also repeated in all your helpers:

```
user = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
```

---

In the above case, however, all the attributes belong to a single object. So why not pass this single object instead?

userForm.js:

```
Template.userForm.user = function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
}
```

userForm.html:

```
<template name="userForm">
    <span data-id="{{user._id}}">
        Name: {{user.name}}, email: {{user.email}}
    </span>
</template>
```

or even:

```
<template name="userForm">
    {{#with user}}
        <span data-id="{{_id}}">
            Name: {{name}}, email: {{email}}
        </span>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to define a global helper, especially when using `Session` variables, which is going to be a lot more flexible and allow for use across multiple templates:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getUserProperty", function(field) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));
    return user && user[field];
});
```

Then, you can use this with `{{getUserProperty "username"}}` or something like that. You can also allow the `field` argument to be a bit more fancy so that you can use something like `"profile.name"` and repeatedly index into the object. Something like the following, although you could definitely support more parsing logic:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getUserProperty", function(field) {
    var item = Meteor.users.findOne(Session.get('edit-user'));

    var keys = field.split(".");

    $(keys).each( function(idx, value) {
        item = item && item[value];
    });

    return item;
});
```

One thing to note: you should probably be using `var` more when declaring local variables. You don't have to do it in Coffeescript but it is pretty essential in Javascript.

Comment: I tried the first helper above and I get back 'undefined'.  When I add console.log statements I see that I am getting a valid user, however the `user[field]` syntax doesn't return data as expected.

Comment: What are you passing into `field`?

Comment: Are you passing it in quotes or no quotes? The argument needs to be a string literal.

Comment: I am passing the field name as a string in double quotes: "profile.name"